# Calculate Day 7 retention rate of all players acquired on specific data

Tags: sql

I'm  new to SQL and I'm struggling with few of the questions on my exercise. How to calculate Day 7 retention rate of all players acquired on 01 October 2019. The tables shown is just a sample of what the extended table is.

My answer was:

```
SELECT 
  Session_table,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as active_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT future_ user_id) as retained_users,
  CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT future_ user_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS float) retention
FROM inapp_purchase
LEFT JOIN user_id as future_id 
ON user_id = future_ user_id
AND user_id. inapp_purchase = user_id.session_table - datetime(page_views.pv_ts, '+7 day')
GROUP BY 1
```

There are two tables:

[session_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ore9N.png)

When each *user_id* starts a session , the session will have a unique *session_id*. *Session_length_seconds* tells how long a session lasted in seconds. *level* tells what game level the player was at the end of that session. The session_table will have one line for each session each user has (users can have multiple sessions per day each with unique *session_id*).

[inapp_purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJWB8.png)

The **inapp_purchase** table has one line for each product that the user (denoted by *user_id*) purchased. There can be multiple purchases in a day per user, per session. The *session_id* and *user_id* here can link to the **session_table** to track active users who also make a payment. *Product_id* tells which product was purchased and the *purchase_value* tells the amount the user paid in $.

There are also three requests for the **inapp_purchase** table:

- Calculate daily average revenue per daily active user for last 3 months
- Calculate the daily average revenue per **paying** user year to date?
- Calculate the daily conversion rate over the last month? This measure is defined by the proportion of daily active users who make a purchase on the day in question.

Please let me know if the above information is sufficient.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS` should help you here

Comment: I suppose this is an interview question from a gaming company?

Comment: @JamesHuang. Yes. I would like to see if there any alternatives on how to approach question.